# Excel: Duplicate names in column A, unique data in column B. I want one row for each unique name with multiple column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help getting a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
Smith, A.   Education       
Smith, A.   Government      
Smith, A.   Marketing
```

To look have the name listed once and the three words listed in separate columns:

```
Smith, A.   Education   Government  Marketing
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a problem you can't really solve without a macro, As @DavidPostill commented, this site is not about creating free code, please have some research on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without VBA. Here is a sample spreadsheet with formulas that will transfix the data.

[image]

1. Use Advanced Filter to Copy Unique Names into Column G.
2. In D2 place `=COUNTIF(A:A,G2)` and drag down
3. In E2 place `=MATCH(G2,A:A,0)-2` and drag down
4. Place the numbers seen in the screenshot in `H8:K8`
5. Place the formula from the formula bar in the screenshot in `H2` and drag over and down. Formula is `=If(H$8<=$D2,OFFSET($A$1,$E2+H$8,1),"")`

Comment: Nice!, could you also include the =if() formula so it could be copied?

Comment: @scott Holtzman, that worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!  I really don't know what a script, VBA or macro is, but I do understand formulas.  You are a life saver!

Comment: Glad it worked for you @GMKoehler. Please mark this as the answer if it is indeed such.

Comment: Edited @Davesexcel.